# How to display multiple callouts from MKAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I like implement sth. like this. I have two annotations with callouts, but MKMapView allows only one to be selected at the same time.

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:self.firstAnnotation animated:FALSE];
[mapView selectAnnotation:self.secondAnnotation animated:FALSE];
```

When I select another annotation, the first one deselected automatically.

But in the picture below, it's successfully implemented. So how can this be done?
http://oi52.tinypic.com/14t3t09.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also see "Multiple annotation callouts displaying in MKMapView":
[Multiple annotation callouts displaying in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417952/multiple-annotation-callouts-displaying-in-mkmapview)

It appears that the framework does not support multiple selections, so you will have to implement custom callouts for this behavior.  The answer to the linked question suggests making your callout a part of your annotation view so you can manage the selection yourself.  Personally I like implementing the callout as an separate annotation - I have an example project with custom callouts here:

https://github.com/jacobjennings/JJMapCallout

which was my solution to:

[MKAnnotationView - Lock custom annotation view to pin on location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392931/mkannotationview-lock-custom-annotation-view-to-pin-on-location-updates/7363862#7363862)

In this project, I forward the MKMapView delegate methods

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
```

to the respective annotation.  This allows me to implement expected callout behaviors.  However, you could ignore didDeselectAnnotationView messages to leave callouts visible.

To find out if the user taps on the map to clear annotations (didn't tap on a pin), check the value of mapView.selectedAnnotations in your didDeselectAnnotationView method, and if it's empty, you'll know to clear your callouts.

Comment: read the other solution you linked to and noticed you changed the megaupload link there, you should change this link too! Nice work...