# Why have only one view pin annotation display?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

I am using following code and it display only one pin(annotation) on Map view. Please help me to figure out my mistake.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
    {
        //Here

        NSLog(@"didAddAnnotationViews");

        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:2] animated:NO];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:3] animated:NO];

          }
```

Why have only one view pin annotation display?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [Multiple annotation callouts in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417952/multiple-annotation-callouts-displaying-in-mkmapview): Multiple annotation callouts displaying in MKMapView

It appears that you will have to implement custom callouts for this behavior. Personally I like implementing subclass the MKAnnotationView to implement a custom one.

Comment: I mean callout...^^ how to display multi callout at the same time!     http://oi52.tinypic.com/14t3t09.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [sample](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/). Even has the sample code. It may help for what you are looking for.