# MKMapView Multiple Callout Display

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to show callout for more than one pin (without tapping) in my map view. How it can be done? Is there any default way or is there any library available. If you can quote me an example code I would be grateful.

Comment: you must have to do RND before putting a question, find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417952/multiple-annotation-callouts-displaying-in-mkmapview?rq=1

Comment: this is not the solution i am not asking for makaanotationviews i am asking for multiple annotation views showing multiple callout views.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box since the callout indicates which pin the user tapped on. I am also not aware of any third party library that would add support for that.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be possible with regular callouts, if the popup windows you want are not interactive, you could fake it by making the MKAnnotationView of the look like an expanded window.