# Selecting all annotations on a map Swift

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I want to select all the annotations on my map so the annotations callout is shown. Right now I can only select one by doing:

```
map.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

How do I select all of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple annotation callouts displaying in MKMapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417952/multiple-annotation-callouts-displaying-in-mkmapview)

Comment: This has already been answered here and the answer is to implement you own callout mechanism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417952/multiple-annotation-callouts-displaying-in-mkmapview