# How to show all annotations call out Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, callout

I have an app which has a lot of annotations and I want to have their call outs open at the beginning(and if its possible never disappear).
What I accomplished since now is to have only one always appeared and when I tap the map it disappears with this line:

```
 mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations[1], animated: true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did some research and I found that ***it's not possible*** from public API and MKMapView mechanisms.

The code below just select an annotation and in the same time deselect the previous one.

```
for annotation in mapView.annotations {
     mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
}
```

So to provide the behavior you've described you have to implement some custom mechanism.

Also, you might look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112945/5433235) answer. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I don't have any annotations call out (where should I put this loop, now I put it inside viewdidload where all my code for map is)

Comment: Yes I was running a test program and I forgot the second title now I put it the second title only showed the last annotation call out

Comment: it also showed me only the last annotation. so I will subtract a mark for now.